# Pylint incorrectly assumes that type is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pylint, mypy

I have the following code:

```py
config = wandb.config

do_something_with_config(config['bar'], config['foo'])
```

For some reason, every time I access a key of `config`, pylint gives an `unsubscriptable-object` error. I can add a `# pylint: disable=unsubscriptable-object` in every place I access a key of this object, but I'd really rather avoid that since I do so in a ton of places.

I tried changing it to `config : Dict[object, str] = wandb.config` and that did not resolve the problem. Is there anything I can do to inform mypy that this value is subscriptable?

Answer (score 1):

This smells like a bug in pylint... there's a relevant issue at https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1498.

---

One would expect pylint to work, especially when type-hinting the types of the objects.

After you call, `wandb.init()`, the `wandb.config` object is of type `wandb.Config`. You can set its type upon assignment.

```py
import wandb

wandb.init()

config: wandb.Config = wandb.config
print(config["bar"], config["foo"])
```

Before you call `wandb.init()`, `wandb.config` is a function. The purpose of the function is to inform the user that wandb must be initialized.

Comment: This did not cause the errors to go away.

Comment: yes i can reproduce this... this could be a bug in pylint: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1498

Comment: Okay, thanks. I guess for now I'll just disable that warning for the whole file.